# Unable to create Bootstrap Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create html page using bootstrap, In that I'm unable to create this `<div>`. And these `<div>` has to be responsive as well.
[Image of div to be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRrmG.png)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="bord2 col-md-4">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bord col-md-4">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>

    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bord col-md-4">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>

    <ul>

      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: First of all try it your self if problem then post it with full code...!

Comment: Do we look like your employees? Try it your self and if there is any issues, we'll help you.

Comment: Provide the code you're using so we can help out, following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: here is the code pls help:<div class="row">
  <div class="bord2 col-md-4">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bord col-md-4">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>

    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bord col-md-4">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>

    <ul>

      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>

    </ul>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside container:

```
<div class="container">
...your code...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For making it responsive add all the classes of bootstrap like this `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4`. these are the classes used in bootstrap for responsiveness. `LG` means large desktop `md` refer to tablet screen size and xs and sm for small and xtra small mobile screen.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           </head>
           <body>
             <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
  <div class="bord2 col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-3" style="background-color:green">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bord col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color:blue">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>

    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bord col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color:grey">
    <h4 class="grey card-title">ABCD</h4>

    <ul>

      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
             </div>
           </body>
           </html>
```

As you are starting with bootstrap I would recommend you to go through [this tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)